# Spring Boot - connect resource server to Spring Session with an Redis server

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

For evaluation purposes we would like to use Spring Session in combination with an Embedded-Redis server.

When using Spring Boot 2.6.7 with JDK17 we start the Spring Session with an Embedded-Redis server. The server is started just after the 'UI' server. The code and config is given at the end.

The 'resource' server that is receiving the Spring Session token cannot connect to redis.

The resource server code is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ResourceApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceApplication.class);

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
  @RequestMapping("/")
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, allowedHeaders = { "x-auth-token", "x-requested-with", "x-xsrf-token" })
  public Message home() {
    logger.info( "ResourceServer: home()");
    return new Message("Hello World");
  }
  @Bean
  HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
    return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The properties are:

security.sessions=NEVER
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379

The dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When adding e.g. the spring-session-data-redis

The error message is:

> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt
> was made from the following location:
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.customize(RedisSessionConfiguration.java:80)

When adding the spring-sessions-data-redis dependency, gives the same error message.

Only for your information, starting up the Redis-embedded server goes like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoApplication {
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
  private RedisServer redisServer;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void startRedis() throws IOException {
    try {
      redisServer = RedisServer.builder().setting("maxheap 256Mb").port(6379).build();
      redisServer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void stopRedis(){
    redisServer.stop();
  }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The resources:

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.session.store-type=redis
```